# can we write PHP foreach loop inside jQuery document ready?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, calendar

I am showing all events date wise for that I am using dnCalendar. I am getting all the events with dates from the database and storing in an array. I have to write a `foreach` loop for all events to list out them in the calendar.

Any jQuery calendar obviously loads in the document.ready method. I want to print all the event dates dynamically and for that I have to print my PHP array in the calendar initialization function, but my problem here is the calendar initialization is in document.ready method.

I think document.ready method loads before the document is ready but I get my PHP array after loading the document only, so my question here is can we print a php array inside jQuery's document.ready method?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var my_calendar = $("#dncalendar-container").dnCalendar({
  minDate: "2016-01-15",
  maxDate: "2100-12-31",
  monthNames: [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ], 
  monthNamesShort: [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mey', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ],
  dayNames: [ 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat' ],
  dayNamesShort: [ 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat' ],
  notes: [
     <?php if(isset($cal_events) && !empty($cal_events)){
            foreach($cal_events as $each_event){ ?>
             { "date": "<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($each_event['event_date'])) ?>", "note": ["<?php echo $each_event['event_title']?>"] },
                    <?php    } }
                    ?>
                    ], 
   showNotes: true,
   startWeek: 'monday',
   dayClick: function(date, view) {
      ------------------
      -------------
   }
 });
 my_calendar.build();
});
```

I want to print the event dates in events part of javascript like below:

```
notes: [
        { "date": "2017-12-25", "note": ["Cristmas"] },
        { "date": "2017-12-31", "note": ["Year End"] },
        { "date": "2018-1-1", "note": ["Year STart"] }
       ],
```

Is my above written php foreach loop is correct or not? Any help, Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I have written ajax call for getting all events and fetching the data successfully but **my problem here is after fetching the data how to print the respose in ajax success method?**

```
notes: [
  $.ajax({
          url: "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/ajax/getEventsList",
          type: "POST",
          data: "",
          success: function(response){
             console.log(response);
             document.write(response);
          }
   })
],
```

ajax response is:

```
{ "date": "2017-12-28", "note": ["event1"] },{ "date": "2017-12-26", "note": ["event2"] },{ "date": "2017-12-27", "note": ["event3"] },{ "date": "2017-12-28", "note": ["event4"] },
```

Comment: So long as the output from your PHP is syntactically correct JS code, then yes you can.

Comment: I'd recommend using `json_encode` rather than string-ing it together by hand

Comment: `I think document.ready method loads before the document is ready` this is not possible, by the very definition of the event. `I get my PHP array after loading the document only` this is not also not possible as PHP is executed on the server, long before any code is even sent to the client.

Comment: Correct Rory. I'd suggest using ajax so get the results then.

Comment: You can only do this if you are creating the Javascript out of a PHP script. If you mean can you run PHP code when the Javascript is running in the browser then No you cannot

Comment: hey Thanks. looks like your idea will work, I will try using ajax @Gavin Simpson

Comment: Hello Gavin, I have updated my question, could you please check it once & tell me how to print the ajax response? @Gavin

Comment: You are very close. Create a 'div' in your document (eg "<div id='mydiv'></div>", then format the response and do "('#mydiv").html(response);". That will put the response into the div. There are many questions and answers on stackoverflow about this.

Comment: Thanks but I knew this(appending response to a div by it's id), I did several times in our projects. What I want here is I have to print (or) echo the response then & there only in the ajax success method only like `notes: [
        { "date": "2017-12-25", "note": ["Cristmas"] },
        { "date": "2017-12-31", "note": ["Year End"] },
        { "date": "2018-1-1", "note": ["Year STart"] }
       ],`. I think it is possible with php's echo only, something like <?php echo $response ?>

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348455/getting-ajax-script-response-in-php-variable and see if it helps. I don't know offhand.